# How do I escape the word "And" in Elasticsearch if I want to search by the literal "And"?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to search over an index that includes constellation code names, and the code name for the Andromeda constellation is `And`.

Unfortunately, if I search using `And`, all results are returned. This is the only one that doesn't work, across dozens of constellation code names, and I assume it's because it's interpreted as the logical operator `AND`.

`(constellation:(And))` returns my entire result set, regardless of the value of `constellation`.

Is there a way to fix this without doing tricks like indexing with an underscore in front?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your mapping? What's the full query?

Comment: @JoeSorocin I don't know about the mapping. I use `django-haystack` to interface to Elasticsearch. I have retracted a couple of other terms from the query, but other than them that's how I see it.

Comment: I suppose sharing the [`Model`](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/searchindex_api.html) should be enough too.

Comment: @JoeSorocin see this PR: https://github.com/astrobin/astrobin/pull/2149/files - you see a `constellation = CharField()` and you see also how it's prepared. Now I just added `__` prefix and suffix so at least it works with this hack. Bit if you have a proper solution, it's better! :)

Comment: How about using a `regexp` query and using `AND` as your pattern? Kind of a workaround/trick/hack but if you’re trying to avoid re-indexing, it’s certainly a way to go about it. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Comment: @Stpete111 since it's a new addition to the model, I will reindex anyway, so that's not a deciding factor. And I'm guessing the regexp query will be a bit slower?

Comment: Yes definitely has some performance impact, but not significant in my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for a bit of a hack, indexing the constellation as `__Foo__` and then changing my search query accordingly by adding the `__` prefix and suffix to the selected constellation.